# Max line length of 1023 in iESS (R in emacs)?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

When I try to enter the line below into R in an iESS buffer, it doesn't work -- it prints out ^G and hangs until I press Ctrl-C.  It's 1024 characters long.  If I shorten the line by one character, it works as expected.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Thanks.

I'm using emacs 25.1 (9.0).  ESS installed via spacemacs on macOS Sierra.

a=c("2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345678","2345780")

Comment: FWIW, on my Windows  machine, running Emacs version 25.1.1 and ESS version 16.10 (installed using Vincent Goulet's installer), this line is handled just fine. I don't see anything in my `.emacs` that seems like it would affect this, but I could of course be missing something...

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report.  It's probably related to commit 9a747ba6507e64e26f87c5173d25428c99b70adb.